# Distinguishing between Layers and TableView using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am working with ArcMap and am using ArcPy.

My task is to loop through MXDs and find broken data sources.

My code is:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
brknMXD = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)
for brknItem in brknMXD:  
    if brknItem.supports("workspacePath"):
        try:
            source = brknItem.workspacePath
            print  str(brknItem) + ": " +  source
        except:
            print "unexpected error"
            continue
    else:
        print "Layer does not support source"
```

Some MXDs have TableViews and that is where the code breaks.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "P:\Scripts\Find_MXDs_Broken_Sources.py", line 5, in 
> if brknItem.supports("workspacePath"): AttributeError: 'TableView' object has no attribute 'supports'

I checked within an MXD Python interpreter to see what type of objects are return by arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd) and it indicated:

```
>>> for each in brknMXD:
...     print type(each)
...     
<class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>
<class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>
<class 'arcpy._mapping.Layer'>
<class 'arcpy._mapping.TableView'>
```

Clearly I can just set a test to distinguish between these two types, but I don't know how exactly to write it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271220/distinguishing-between-layers-and-tableview-using-arcpy#comment431792_271220):

> You could use the describe statement
>   http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001w000000
>   and look at the dataType, it should be Layer or TableView for the two
>   indicated types, though I'm not sure how well it works with broken
>   objects... give it a go and see what you get: if
>   arcpy.Describe(brknItem).dataType == 'Layer': before .supports(..
>   line.

and as [commented by @BenSNadler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271220/distinguishing-between-layers-and-tableview-using-arcpy#comment431846_271220):

> You can use listLayers and listTables and check if each one is broken
>   Or as noted above, check the type before .supports